# ビルトインサーバー起動時のメッセージがコマンドプロンプト上で文字化けする

Tags: php, コマンドプロンプト

今までXampp上でphpを学習していました。

今回は別の教材でPHPの最新バージョンをダウンロードし、ファイル作成　→　ビルトインサーバーでブラウザに反映させるという動作を学習しています。

作成したphpファイルには以下のように記述しています。

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

そのうえコマンドプロンプト上でビルトインサーバーを立ち上げるために以下のコードを実行しました。

```
desktop\code-php> php -S localhost:8000
```

[image: cmd]

ここで**文字化け**が発生しています。

ブラウザへ

```
localhost:8000/info.php
```

と打ち込むと実行結果は間違いなく返ってきています。コマンドプロンプト内で文字化けしている理由が分かりません。詳しい方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。初心者です。よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: phpinfo]

Comment: 「xampp php 日本語 文字化け」と言ったキーワードで検索して見つかるこんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [XAMPPの文字化けをphp.iniの設定で直す方法【初心者向け】](https://techacademy.jp/magazine/2412), [XAMPPの文字化けを回避する方法とは？【php.iniで修正】](https://webukatu.com/wordpress/blog/28125/), [【前置きなし】XAMPP日本語文字化け対策 文字コードをUTF-8にする方法 Windows10 【2019年4月版】](https://sainoitnote.com/xampp-misconversion-counterplan-win10-201904/) あるいはコマンドプロンプトの文字コード設定等かもしれません。[Powershellの文字化けを直す方法](https://www.oresamalabo.net/entry/2021/09/15/003143)

Comment: どうもまずは`php.ini`の`extention_dir`あたりから始めて必要な設定を正しく行うのが良さそうですね。[php.iniファイルの作成と初期設定](https://www.javadrive.jp/php/install/index5.html), [拡張モジュールのディレクトリ設定](http://phpbook.s25.xrea.com/install/phpini/index3.html)